# combres creates links to files in head element but page renders with no styles or scripts

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, combres

My asp.net MVC 3 site using Combres renders fine on my workstation.  When I compile the same code on my laptop the combres links are there with the correct paths, but the page renders without styles. When I use firebug on the site that works I get the following class appended to the html element:

class=" js no-flexbox flexbox-legacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage no-websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients no-cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths"

This class set does not appear on my laptop site. Log4Net shows no errors.

When I expand the combres file link in firebug it says "Reload the page to get source for:..." Needless to say, that doesn't work.

Both systems are running windows 7 64 bit and IIS 7.5.  It doesn't work in IE on my laptop either.  When I go to the workstation site from my laptop it also works.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.  I am at a complete loss.

Answer (score 0):

The new flexbox got put into modernizr, but the browser support as of now is just Chrome 17+.

That is why checking flexbox in the build panel only adds the flexbox CSS class to the HTML tag, not flexbox-legacy.

You can just use an old version of `modernizer.js`. Or even remove that file if not needed.